# Расположение кнопок в форме ромба

Tags: android, android-xml

View имеют фон ромба. Необходимо расположить "кнопки" так как на картинке.

Сделал я вот такой разметкой, но при этом если размера пространства недостаточно то эти кнопки начинают плющится. Как в моем случае можно отвязаться от статичных размеров? Или может подскажете как можно по другому сделать такое расположение?

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lastInfoTime"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/navigation"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
          android:background="@drawable/button_nav_background"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/auto"
          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

         <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
             android:id="@+id/navigationText"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:drawablePadding="7dp"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_gas_station"
             android:fontFamily="@font/pfdindisplaypro_light"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Навигация"
             android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
             android:textSize="13sp" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/auto"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
          android:background="@drawable/button_nav_background"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/navigation"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

         <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
             android:id="@+id/autoText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:drawablePadding="7dp"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/truck"
             android:fontFamily="@font/pfdindisplaypro_light"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Авто"
             android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
             android:textSize="13sp" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/message"
          android:layout_width="140dp"
          android:layout_height="140dp"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@id/navigation"
          android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@id/navigation"
          android:background="@drawable/button_nav_background"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical">

         <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
             android:id="@+id/messageText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:drawablePadding="7dp"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_message"
             android:fontFamily="@font/pfdindisplaypro_light"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Сообщения"
             android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
             android:textSize="13sp" />
      </LinearLayout>


   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте ConstraintLayout. Все кнопки разместите внутри него и привежите их к его границам. Когда родительский ConstraintLayout будет сжиматься, все кнопки внутри будут автоматически мастабироваться. Отдельно бы я поработал с минимальным и максимальным размером кнопок. Если они станут слишком маленькими - это не удобно. Если слишком большими - некрасиво.

**Дополнение:**

Попробую объяснить на примере 1 пары. Свяжите цепью верхнюю и нижнюю, размеры кнопок установите match parent для высоты кнопок, для ширины wrap_content. Задайте кнопкам соотношение 1 к 1 (у констреинта это свойство точно есть, не уверен про обычный релетив лейаут).  Отцентруйте обе кнопки горизонтально.установите падинг между кнопками и от нижней-верхней границы. Затем подобное нужно проделать для левой и правой кнопки

**Реализация**
Обычно не в моих правилах давать решение, но в этот раз проблема мне показалась необычной (я был не уверен, что все учел), поэтому я попробовал и у меня получилось:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:background="#0026ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/navigationText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Right"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:background="#ffb700"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/autoText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Left"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/navigationText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Top"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="#4cff00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/autoText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Bottom"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

А выглядит это вот так (я использовал простые квадраты, но с ромбами накладки исчезнут):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно как я могу это сделать в ConstraintLayout, с этим лаяутом я только только начал работать. Не могли бы подсказать как можно заставить кнопки расположиться таким образом как на картинке выше?

Comment: дополнил, надеюсь что я все учел

Comment: ССпасибо, только не понял, как и к чему верхнюю кнопку привязать. Так чтобы при масштабировании они все вместе ходили не нарушая общего вида. @+id/message является верхней кнопкой. Обновил вопрос

Comment: добавил возможное решение. попробуйте его применить

Comment: работает. Спасибо. Буду вникать в данную разметку)

Comment: Получается если убрать @+id/bottom то данная разметка не будет работать?

Comment: Верстка сделана под 4 ромбовидные кнопки. Если их вдруг станет три, то она перекоситься. Если что, 4-ую кнопку вы можете просто скрыть (особенно если она то должна быть видна то нет)

Comment: Пока так и сделал, скрыл. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: потом обязательно на досуге попробуйте сделать с 3-мя